# Is not there a coding style violation on PHP: 'else die();'

Tags: php, coding-style

I have a computer science undergrad degree and during first year, during algorithm lessons, it is pushed into my head that i should not put `return` in any of condition branches; `if, else`.

[The question and some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676678/in-an-if-else-statement-for-a-method-return-should-an-else-be-explicitly-stated) support me. But there is a matter about my first PHP web site building experiment. PHP code samples on the Web tell that we 'must' use `else die();`.

I have prepared a Web site with 'my truth in my mind' without doing all the controls to handle all possible errors without any undesirable view on the pages of Web site. The database connection have exploded, thus some smart ***es tell me that i should use `else die();`.

Comment: It depends of the if statement. Sometimes you will want thw code to die().

Comment: So basically, the real problem was that you didn't cover all possible outcomes and then someone, probably a newbie or just horrible programmer (there's many of them, we should call them "normal programmers") told you to use `else die;` - well you don't have to. There's no rule saying you MUST or even SHOULD use such coding style. But, you should ensure that all abnormal program errors are handled so you don't get weird stuff when your db connection explodes.

Comment: @N.B.  THANKS! This comment supported my ego :) Would you mind to copy and paste it as an answer , then i can vote up and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Different coding styles have varying rules and there are many of them, so while that may violate a style that you've been taught, that doesn't mean it's a wrong thing to do.

Coding style recommendations are just that - recommendations; not a law. Their goal is to provide you with a set of rules that usually result in better-readable code. However, they are always influenced by somebody's own *preferences* and do not in any way mean that a piece of code is invalid.

Pick one and stick to it for your own benefit, but don't be surprised that other people have different coding styles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you are right, thus, putting the idea in front to a mirror; neither somebody should criticize my obsessive coding style even though i have not test all the code yet, nor talk down for a subject that i meet through my obsessive and maybe little neurotic undergrad Dr.s.