# C# Loop back to a previous part of code

Tags: c#, loops

```
//Gender Creation:
while (correct == 0)
{
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a gender from the options below: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Male|Female|Random");
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        Gender = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (Gender == "MALE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is this the gender you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (Input == "YES")
            {
                correct = 1;
            }
            else if (Input == "NO")
            {
                correct = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (Gender == "FEMALE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is this the gender you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (Input == "YES")
            {
                correct = 1;
            }
            else if (Input == "NO")
            {
                correct = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (Gender == "RANDOM")
        {
            correct = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR, Please try again.");
            Gender = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        }
    } while (correct == 0);

    //Random Gender Creation:
    if (correct == 2)
    {
        do
        {
            if (randgender == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The gender: MALE was randomly chosen");
                Console.WriteLine("Is this the gender you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
                Console.Write("Input: ");
                Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (Input == "YES")
                {
                    correct = 1;
                    Gender = "MALE";
                }
                else if (Input == "NO")
                {
                    correct = 2;
                }
            }
            else if (randgender == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The gender: FEMALE was randomly chosen");
                Console.WriteLine("Is this the race you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
                Console.Write("Input: ");
                Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (Input == "YES")
                {
                    correct = 1;
                    Gender = "FEMALE";
                }
                else if (Input == "NO")
                {
                    correct = 2;
                }
            }
        } while (correct == 2);
        correct = 0;
    }
    break;
}
```

When `correct = 2` then the gender is being randomly generated, if the user inputs no when being asked if they are happy with the gender the code will just loop the random gender generator over and over constantly saying that the random gender is the same every time as the random number is never changing however when `correct = 0` the code will just proceed when no is inputted and when the gender is printed it is just printed as RANDOM as that is the option the user initially chose.

How can I make it go back to the first do while loop to ask the user what gender they want their character to be?

Comment: If reading a 6-line sentence wasn't bad enough, the code is enough to make me want to get a beer.

Comment: Unfortunately mate i'm rather new to c#, with only doing it in my computer science lessons a couple of times a week, what i'm trying to say is that i need a way to loop back from the second do while loop to the first do while loop when the user inputs NO when being asked whether they are happy with the random gender chosen for them.

Comment: Break your program down into smaller bits. What is it that you need to achieve, in plain English? Step 1, 2, etc.

Comment: Ok: 1: when the user is asked what gender they would like to be they have the option of random. 2:When they choose random the user is told the gender that was randomly generated and then asked if they are happy with that gender.3:When prompted whether they want to use the random gender or not if they input no I need it to loop back to the question of Male, female or random. However when "correct = 2" after the user inputs no the code will just loop the same are you happy with this gender question. if "correct = 0" then it will just proceed with the rest of the program but not log a gender.

Comment: You are also rather new to StackOverflow.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Methods (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) will be helpful I guess. Also have a look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676678/in-an-if-else-statement-for-a-method-return-should-an-else-be-explicitly-stated)

Answer (score 1):

As theMayer suggested, you'll need to break down your app into smaller pieces.  There are also a few concepts that you may need to tackle before you can write C#, as such.

This example might help you get a little further along, as it illustrates several ways of achieving better control flow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear();

    var choosenGender = "";
    var wasChoiceConfirmed = false;

    while (wasChoiceConfirmed == false)
    {
        choosenGender = PromptForGender();

        switch (choosenGender)
        {
            case "RANDOM":
                var randomGender = GenerateRandomGender();
                wasChoiceConfirmed = PromptForGenderConfirmation(randomGender, true);
                break;
            case "MALE":
            case "FEMALE":
                wasChoiceConfirmed = PromptForGenderConfirmation(choosenGender);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error, please try again. \n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

static string PromptForGender()
{
    Console.Write(
        "\nPlease choose a gender from the options below: \n" +
        "Male|Female|Random \n" +
        "Input:");
    return Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
}

static bool PromptForGenderConfirmation(string gender, bool wasRandom = false)
{
    var randomVerbiage = wasRandom ? "randomly " : "";
    Console.Write(
        $"\nThe gender: {gender} was {randomVerbiage}chosen \n" +
        "Is this the gender you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: \n" +
        "Input: ");
    var confirmed = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
    return confirmed == "YES";
}

static string GenerateRandomGender()
{
    var randomNumber = new Random();
    return randomNumber.Next(0, 1) == 0 ? "FEMALE" : "MALE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code so it helps me understand it better. This gives you the result you want and you don't need all those nested loops.

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void AskFirstQuestion()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a gender from the options below: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Male|Female|Random");
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        var gender = Console.ReadLine()?.ToUpper();
        if (gender == "MALE" || gender == "FEMALE")
        {
            HandleGenderSelection(gender);
        }
        else if (gender == "RANDOM")
        {
            HandleRandom();
        }
    }

    private static void HandleRandom()
    {
        var randomGender = GenerateRandomGender();
        Console.WriteLine($"The gender: {randomGender} was randomly chosen");
        Console.WriteLine("Is this the race you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine()?.ToUpper();
        switch (input)
        {
            case "YES":
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
                break;
            case "NO":
                AskFirstQuestion();
                break;
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateRandomGender()
    {
        //Have you logic to randomly create gender
        return "MALE";
    }

    private static void HandleGenderSelection(string gender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is this the gender you wish your character to be? Enter Yes/No: ");
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine()?.ToUpper();
        if (input == "YES")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK!");
        }
        else if (input == "NO")
        {
            AskFirstQuestion();
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AskFirstQuestion();
    }
}
```