# If and return is efficient or if and else if is efficient/recommended?

Tags: c#

Could someone tell me which of the below 2 snippets is efficient/recommended and why?

```
private void method1()
{
    if(condition)
    {
    //some code to be executed when the condition is met
    return;
    }
    //some code to be executed when the condition is not met
}

private void method2()
{
    if(condition)
    {
     //some code to be executed when the condition is met
    }
    else
    {
     //some code to be executed when the condition is not met
    }
}
```

The answers given in the below question have not mentioned anything with respect to my question in terms of efficiency or recommended practice, the question looks like it is merely asking for what is right.

[In an If-Else Statement for a method return, should an Else be explicitly stated if it can instead be implicitly followed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676678/in-an-if-else-statement-for-a-method-return-should-an-else-be-explicitly-stated)

Comment: Regarding efficiency, it makes no difference at all. So use whichever makes your code more readable. In a simple case like yours, the `if`/`else` is nice for its symmetry. But, for example, if you have several "guard" tests you want to check at the top of a function and bail out if any of them fail, then it's nice to give each one an `if`/`return` to avoid unnecessary indenting.

Comment: Is that a bottleneck for your app? See also: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Arranging your code naturally to avoid tab mountains is typically good for readability. It makes no difference in performance, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of execution speed, there probably won't be any difference worth thinking about.

In terms of readability, I suggest you take the question another level and see where it leads. These two examples follow your two patterns, but for a less trivial problem. Which is easier to read?

```
void Example1()
{
    if (a)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            if (c)
            {
                D();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Y();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        X();
    }
}

void Example2()
{
    if (!a) 
    {
        X();
        return;
    }
    if (!b)
    {
        Y();
        return;
    }
    if (!c) return;
    D();
}
```

The first pattern would end up using an [Arrow](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) while the second one uses a [Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)). Arrow is considered an anti-pattern.

When you flatten the arrow to use the guard, you reduce [cyclomatic complexity](http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/chetanv/2015/07/04/understanding-cyclomatic-complexity-and-its-importance-in-code-analysis-metrics/), reduce code length, reduce the need to scroll to see a complete code block, and reduce the number of mental manipulations required to understand the meaning of an average line of code.

The second approach is objectively better in nearly every way, with the possible exception of very trivial logic, where an `else` might more clearly communicate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Having trouble picturing it, but you're welcome to add another answer and provide an example.

Comment: I was just thinking that we can get rid of the curly brackets and reduce the code to 3 lines if we remove the `return` statements, make them all `else if` statements, and replace the `!c` check with just `if(c)`. something like: `if (!a) x(); else if (!b) y(); else if (c) d();` Not really important, definitely not worthy of a new answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference in performance. Comparing these two methods in IL:

```
   .method private hidebysig static void  Method1() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (bool V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::condition // Push condition onto stack
    IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1 // Load constant integer 1
    IL_0007:  ceq      // Check if they equal
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0 // Load constant integer 0
    IL_000a:  ceq      // Check if previous compare returned true
    IL_000c:  stloc.0  
    IL_000d:  ldloc.0
    IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0013 // If true then short branch to return

    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  br.s       IL_0013 // Else just to return (the same as IL_000e)

    IL_0013:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Method1

  .method private hidebysig static void  Method2() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (bool V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::condition
    IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0007:  ceq
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000a:  ceq
    IL_000c:  stloc.0
    IL_000d:  ldloc.0
    IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0014

    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  br.s       IL_0016  // We branch but in release I doubt the branch would still exist at runtime.

    IL_0014:  nop
    IL_0015:  nop
    IL_0016:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Method2
```

These `nop` instructions are only visible, because I run this in debug mode. They will not exist in release. Replicable code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Method1();
    Method2();
}
static int condition = 1;

private static void Method1()
{
    if(condition == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
}

private static void Method2()
{
    if(condition == 1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

When optimizing application, first look at what is the real bottleneck. Find what causes the longest delay and start optimizing this. What you are currently trying to do is called **premature optimization**. Because of that your code becomes less readable, probably slower and is more prone to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *MSIL OCD (Obsessive compulsive disorder)*, you can save your self 1 `OpCodes.Nop` by not using the `else` !!!!!

[`OpCodes.Nop` Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.nop.aspx)

> Fills space if opcodes are patched. No meaningful operation is
>   performed although a processing cycle can be consumed.

**Code**

```
private static  int Method1(bool condition)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      return 1+1;
   }
   return 2 + 2;
}
```

**MSIL**

```
IL_0000: nop          

IL_0001: ldarg.0      // condition
IL_0002: stloc.0      // V_0

IL_0003: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0004: brfalse.s    IL_000b

IL_0006: nop          

IL_0007: ldc.i4.2     
IL_0008: stloc.1      // V_1
IL_0009: br.s         IL_000f

IL_000b: ldc.i4.4     
IL_000c: stloc.1      // V_1
IL_000d: br.s         IL_000f

IL_000f: ldloc.1      // V_1
IL_0010: ret
```

**Code**

```
private static int Method2(bool condition)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      return 1 + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      return 2 + 2;
   }
}
```

**MSIL**

```
IL_0000: nop          

IL_0001: ldarg.0      // condition
IL_0002: stloc.0      // V_0

IL_0003: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0004: brfalse.s    IL_000b

IL_0006: nop          

IL_0007: ldc.i4.2     
IL_0008: stloc.1      // V_1
IL_0009: br.s         IL_0010

IL_000b: nop          

IL_000c: ldc.i4.4     
IL_000d: stloc.1      // V_1
IL_000e: br.s         IL_0010

IL_0010: ldloc.1      // V_1
IL_0011: ret
```